# Interpolation question

Tags: interpolation

I have a set of data $(x_i,y_i,y'_i)$, $i=1,\dots,N$ and I want to fit an interpolating curve $f(x)$ which matches both the data $y_i$ and the first derivatives $y'_i$ at the nodes $x_i$,
\begin{align}
f(x_i) &= y_i \\
\frac{d}{dx} f(x_i) &= y'_i
\end{align}
At first I thought that piecewise cubic Hermite interpolation would be well suited for this, however this method imposes no constraints on the second derivatives, and I am finding that the interpolated curve has discontinuous second derivatives at the endpoints, which is undesirable.

So I am think I should impose the additional constraint that the second derivative of $f(x)$ is continuous across the nodes $x_i$. If I consider piecewise polynomials between the nodes, it looks like I would need at least degree 4 polynomials (cubics don't have enough degrees of freedom to match the second derivative constraint). So if define a polynomial of degree 4, $p_k(x)$ on $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$, $k=1,\dots,N-1$, then these piecewise polynomials would have to satisfy these constraints:
\begin{align}
p_k(x_k) &= y_k \\
p'_k(x_k) &= y'_k \\
p_k(x_{k+1}) &= y_{k+1} \\
p'_k(x_{k+1}) &= y'_{k+1} \\
p''_k(x_{k+1}) &= p''_{k+1}(x_{k+1})
\end{align}
The above equations represent a total of $5(N-1) - 1$ constraints. There are a total of $5(N-1)$ unknown parameters if each $p_k(x)$ is a quartic polynomial. This gives me 1 additional degree of freedom, which I could use, for example, to constrain the second derivative either at the beginning or end of the interval (but not both!)

I am a little surprised that such a scheme exhibits this asymmetry, where I can only constrain either $p''_1(x_1)$ or $p''_{N-1}(x_N)$ but not both. Does anyone know of a reference for doing an interpolation like this, and whether there exists a high-quality implementation in some numerical library?

Comment: You're making it an asymmetry! You could be imposing $p_1''(x_1)=p_{N-1}''(x_N)$ :-)

Comment: True, but I don't know that there is a physical reason for the end points to match second derivatives

Comment: @vibe I do not get your question. You first mention that you want a smooth interpolant matching the values $f(x_i)$ and first derivatives collocationwise. A cubic Hermite spline interpolation should be sufficient here. You only have to consider that you have your derivatives already by hand. However, later you are claiming that the method does not impose constraints on the second derivatives. This makes no sense. How smooth should your interpolant be?

Comment: @vibe By the way for a $C^2$ continous spline interpolation you need a piecewise polynomial order of 5. For a $C^1$ continous spline interpolation (Cubic Hermite) you need a polynomial order of 3.

Comment: @ConvexHull why do you need order 5 polynomials for $C^2$? Order 4 should suffice

Comment: @vibe Your question is asked very carelessly. I am assuming we are talking about *piecewice* polynomial (Hermite) interpolation aka spline interpolation. With your *single* additional constraint you are forcing your problem to be global again. You cannot use the wording "piecewice" anymore. You are confusing the idea behind spline interpolation. Simply add two constraints for the second derivatives in each intervall, one for the left and one for the right point. If you do not have the second derivatives by hand, use an approximation.